# custom angularjs filter date time format extra characters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have create this custom angular js filter to format date and time but I have problem the format output is '03/25/2015 19:03 PM3/P3' from where this 3/p3 come from ?my format should be MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM?

javascript

```
app.filter('formatDateAndTime', function () {
    return function (input){
        if (moment.utc(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM') === 'Invalid date')
            return ' ';
        else
            return moment.utc(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM');
    };
});
```

Comment: 3 came from `format`. moment.js replaces M with month which is 3 in your case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment.utc(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM A');
```

For AM/PM you must use `A`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.query = moment();
})
.filter('formatDateAndTime', function () {
    return function (input){
        if (moment.utc(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM') === 'Invalid date')
            return 'invalid ';
        else
            return moment.utc(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM A');
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
{{query | formatDateAndTime}}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I show 09/02/2015 01:09 PM instead of 09/02/2015 13:09 PM?

Answer (score 1):

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM
```

should be

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM A
```

`AM/PM` in moment's formatting in English means (AM/PM)(Month #)/P(Month #). See formatting docs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).